# Как "26.12.17 00:00:00[MSK (UTC +3)]" строку во время в UTC преобразовать?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone

Подскажите библиотеку которая может из такой строки `26.12.17 00:00:00[MSK (UTC +3)]` выдать время в utc.

Comment: А нет ли случайно возможности получить нормальную строку вместо этого непонятно чего? У нас тут есть стандарт — ISO 8601 `2017-12-26T00:00:00+03:00`, если вам удастся получить строку в таком стандартном формате, проблем станет сильно меньше

Comment: [The Python Standard Library 16.3. time — Time access and conversions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)

Comment: На вопрос не ответили. Как с помощью того, на что вы сослались, получить из такой строки время в utc?

Comment: На вопрос ответил - библиотеку подсказал. Не просто подсказал, а даже со ссылкой на оф. документацию. Если человек хочет готовое решение, не приложив минимальных усилий по чтению документации - ему следует поискать занятие, отличное от IT.

Comment: Я читал эту документацию, но тем не менее способа, как распарсить такую строку, я там не нашёл. Если вы не хотите давать готовое решение по такой конкретной задаче и при этом не самой элементарной вещи — вам не место на ruSO :)

Comment: Нет. Это с сайт приходит.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin пока я писал ответ на комментарий, там была формулировка вида «ему не место в IT» )

Comment: С вами интересно дискутировать, но обращаю ваше внимание на то что мой ответ полностью соответствует вопросу :) UPD да, я исправил на более "мягкий" вариант

Comment: @Dmitresso в таком случае обращаю ваше внимание на то, что в общем случае вопросы вида «подскажите библиотеку» считаются недопустимыми и отвечать на них не следует :) На данный момент jfs довёл формулировку вопроса до ума, и теперь ваш ответ точно не является ответом)

Comment: у вас строка буквально на "[MSK (UTC +3)]" заканчивается? Могут быть случаи у вас на входе, когда utc смещение не целый час, c минутами? (в общем случае может быть)

Comment: Да, был результат с +7.30, поэтому этот параметр надо учитывать.

Answer (score 2):

Библиотеки, которая бы произвольную строку со временем смогла бы распознать, нет (даже люди не все форматы понимают точно). Ваш конкретный формат, можно распознать используя регулярные выражения:

```
import datetime as DT
import re

input_string = '27.12.17 16:30:54[IST (UTC +5.30)]'
m = re.fullmatch(r'(\d+\.\d+.\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)\[[^ ]+ \(UTC ([^\)]+)\)\]',
                 input_string)
datetime_string, offset_string = m.groups()
dt = DT.datetime.strptime(datetime_string, '%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S')
hours, minutes = map(int, offset_string.split('.'))
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=DT.timezone(DT.timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes)))
print(dt)      # -> '2017-12-27 16:30:54+05:30'
utc_dt = dt.astimezone(DT.timezone.utc)
print(utc_dt)  # -> '2017-12-27 11:00:54+00:00'
```

Comment: А в Unix timestamp epoch? Как?

Comment: @Andru: это легко, но это отдельный вопрос: «как имея datetime в utc, получить Unix timestamp» или (что почти тоже самое) «как имея datetime с известным utc смещением (timezone-aware) получить Unix time» (если не найдёте существующий Stack Overflow вопрос, то можно новый задать)

Comment: Так я и имел введу Unix timestamp epoch под UTC.